# Android Studio Pls Check Ive been struggling to find a solution to video view being null in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the first time i am asking a question so sorry in advance if I'm not asking in proper format. Im relatively new to kotlin and I would love if anyone could help me. I have made an intro video and wished to display it as a videoview so I made this code but now I'm unable to solve this problem

```
    package com.ai.sleepassistant

    import android.net.Uri
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_intro.*

    class Intro : AppCompatActivity() {


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val offlineUri = Uri.parse("android.resource//:$packageName/${R.raw.introa}")
            if (video_view != null) {
                video_view.setVideoURI(offlineUri)
                video_view.setOnPreparedListener { video_view.start() }
            }
    
       }
     }
```

nothing happens cause the video view is null but to make video view not null it needs to be not null which makes no sense to me and a message comes that a null cant be cast on a non null object and I'm unable to fix it please can someone suggest a solution thank you for any and all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is null is because you haven't assigned a `View` to be displayed in the Activity.
You should be setting a `view` to the Activity first.

Use:
`class Intro : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_intro)` as constructor
or alternatively you can use:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro)` after `super.onCreate()`

Comment: Thank you so much it seems to be working though an error came in the app by android that video cant be played but I think ill figure out why its not working